# how to evaluate this integral in simple form?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

$$f (x)  =\int_{0}^{x} \int_{-\infty}^{\frac{s^2}{2}} e^{s-\frac{t^2}{2}}\, dtds$$

Comment: And what happened when you tried this?

Comment: The question intend to find f(x) in a simple form. My working doesn't manage to solve it in a form without an integral sign

Comment: I understand the question, I am just curious to see what you have tried and how far you have got on the problem. Seeing where you got after changing the order of integration will help us provide a better answer.

Comment: I have added my final step of my attempt.

Comment: Are you certain about the limits and/or the integrand?

Answer (score 3):

Is this simple enough?
$$
\int_{0}^{x}\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{s^2}{2}} e^{s-\frac{t^2}{2}}\,dtds
\int_{0}^{x}\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{s^2}{2}} e^s e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}\,dtds = 
\int_{0}^{x}e^s\,ds  \int_{-\infty}^{\frac{s^2}{2}} e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}\,dt
$$
The first integral is immediate, the second can be written using the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Comment: i expect the Question is asking for a form without integral sign. Your answer would be too easy as that counts as half of a long Question

Comment: @leibnizzzz, I think that a elementary closed form is impossible as $f(x) = (e^x-1)\text{erf}(\text{something})$-

Comment: As the question comes from professor for Christmas holiday, i assume there must be solution.